# Cursor DB not initialised although initialised

Tags: android, database

I have almost everything fine and quadruple checked every other thing related with the db and the cursor, I have a button in a activity upon clicking which the following code runs to access the string from a public function in other class:

```
DatabaseHandler dbfunc = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    String deviceCODE = dbfunc.getUSERdetailsSTRING();
                    Log.i(TAG, deviceCODE);
```

The following is the public function in DB handler class:

```
public String getUSERdetailsSTRING(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
            user.put("Device Code", cursor.getString(5));
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String deviceCODE = user.get(KEY_UID);
        return deviceCODE;
    }
```

**BUT it shows me the following error on logcat:**

```
08-16 22:06:24.840: E/AndroidRuntime(25923): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 22:06:24.840: E/AndroidRuntime(25923): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 5 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
08-16 22:06:24.840: E/AndroidRuntime(25923):    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
08-16 22:06:24.840: E/AndroidRuntime(25923):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
08-16 22:06:24.840: E/AndroidRuntime(25923):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
```

Comment: Close the cursor before return and try again!

Comment: tried already the same - tried before and after both the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The place from where I took the example(http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) that guy started the counting from cursor.getString(1); from ONE However it should be started with a ZERO '0', its solved now!

Comment: He also starts it from ZERO at this tutorial

Comment: Sorry wrong link THE Correct link is this >> http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/